# Java: Issue with try-catch block with child class

Tags: java, eclipse, nullpointerexception, try-catch

I’m developing a web service code in Java (Eclipse Neon), I’ve two model classes for data assignment operations as shown here.

An editor is forcing me to remove try catch block from the constructor of class ‘ChatHistoryModel’ with the message: *Unreachable catch block for JSONException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement 
 body*.

If I remove the try-catch block, it will result in a code crash, when data assignment operation fails to assign data (a nil value). block if with variable is_group_chat throws *null pointer exception*.

How to handle this situation.

```
class TestHistoryModel extends TestModel {
    private Boolean is_read, is_group_chat;

    public TestHistoryModel(JSONObject jsonObject){

        super(jsonObject);
        try {

             // value assignment operations

          if (is_group_chat){  // Null pointer exception line

          }

        } catch (JSONException e) {   // Error line
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}



class TestModel {



    public TestModel(JSONObject jsonObject){

        try {

            // value assignment operations

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Here is a snapshot of error for catch block of class - TestHistoryModel

[image]

Comment: Why does he ask you to remove it?

Comment: Your constructors don't even have the same name as their class, your code shouldn't compile.

Comment: it can be caused by fact, that JSONException is never thrown in corresponding block (are you sure there is a line which is throwing this exception?)

Comment: @Krunal No, I mean, when you hover on the redly underlined JSONObject, what does the editor say? By the way, I copied your code on my editorand it works.

Comment: A NullPointerException is not a JSONException. Looks like you are catching the wrong exception. But you really shouldn't catch NullPointerExceptions and instead debug the method that throws them.

Comment: Pl. suggest me, how can I solve this. Added complete information about issue I'm facing here

Comment: You try to catch an exception that is never thrown AND you are using a `Boolean` that is null, meaning that the JVM try to call a method on a null instance. That explain both of your problem. You can "correct" both by catch the `NullPointerException` but I doubt this is what you want, and this is not what you should do either. Just check that your `Boolean` instance is not null before you check is content (has you use `Boolean` insteand of `boolean`

Comment: Thank you all, AxelH, Nathan & OH GOD SPIDERS.. I found solution with all of your help. I assigned default value to variable group chat. is_group_chat = false and it solved my issue for null pointer exception. But editor forced me to remove try catch.

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: @Krunal read the JLS link in my answer to understand completly the reason the compiler dont' accept your catch. As the default value, you should ask yourself the need of that condition if you never set a value to that boolean.

Comment: @AxelH Yest I just read that and it found very useful. With help of it, I changed my JSONException into NullPointerException to keep try-catch block at is it. Thank you...

Comment: @Krunal You should not catch NPE to quickly as those should not happen, you should be able to prevent a NPE. Also, note that if you catch it, it will catch that NPE for any code in that try catch, even in a method, called by a method, call by a constructor. So you could miss a NPE that is not the one you catched here.

Comment: @AxelH Yes, to prevent NPE, I've assigned default values to all Primitive variables and not null conditions for all non-primitive variables. I need keep try-catch to return something as response of web request query to a web service call, when it fails to provide required information to request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1 JSONException**

[`JSONException`](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONException.html) is a checked-exception. That means that you can't catch it if it is never thrown in the try statement. You can remove it as it is not necessary. Read that [JLS Chapiter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3) to get more information.

**2 NullPointerException**

Accessing a `Boolean` instance like you do `if(is_group_chat)` is the equivalent to `if(is_group_chat.booleanValue())`, as it is null, you get that `NullPointerException`.

1. Check if the instance is null before checking it
2. Use a `boolean` insteand of the auto-boxed class
3. See [OH GOD SPIDERS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44500469/4391450) to see an alternative condition

Comment: This assumes he's using org.json.JSONException, but if he is, then that's totally on point.

Comment: @Nathan From the question : "_Unreachable catch block for JSONException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body_" This means that OP used a `JSONException` that is not extending `RuntimeException`. Any other API would still be correct, I just add this like to point the importance of the _checked-exception_ for the "catch clause".

Comment: Indeed, I answered before he added the exception error message. I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are getting the "Unreachable catch block" message because JSONException is a checked exception and nothing inside your try block is declared to be able to throw that JSONException. So this Exception will never be thrown inside your try block and the catch block never used.

Since the try catch block is unnecessary and won't fix your original problem you should simply remove it.

2. You are getting a NullPointerException because you are using a Boolean object that is null and Java will try to autounbox it into a small boolean.

To make it NullPointerException safe change

```
if (is_group_chat)
```

to

```
if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(is_group_chat))
```

If `is_group_chat` is still null the method `Boolean.TRUE.equals` will return false.

Your try catch blocks can be removed and really are the wrong way to solve this problem.

Another solution would bee to change `is_group_chat` to a small `boolean`. But keep in mind that those will be initialized with `false` as a default value.

Comment: The question would be on the first place, why those `Boolean`s are there and used but not initialized. But that condition is indeed a good solution

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS You should reformulate your answer to answer the original question, i.e. why does his compiler ask him to remove the catch block.

Comment: @Nathan AFAICS there isn't actually a specific question.

Comment: @SteveSmith It changed a bit with the edits, but it was "Why do my editor tell me this catch block is unreachable" :p

Comment: @Nathan funny thing is that you wrote an answer that doesn't answer it at all either...

Comment: i could have bet that there must already be enough duplicates for the "Unreachable catch block" error but couldn't find any good dupe i could link to. :-/

Answer (score 2):

In Java, there are two types of exceptions: **checked** and **unchecked**. Checked exceptions extends from `Exception` while unchecked from `RuntimeException`. If some method is throwing checked exception, that method must have in signature `throws {SomeCheckedException}` unless it handles this exception in method body. This way we are saying: *take extra care, this method may fail*.

Here is an example how to handle **checked exceptions**:

```
public List<String> getFileLines(Path filePath) throws IOException {
    // this line is throwin checked exception "IOException" therefore, 
    // we need to rethrow this exception since it is not handled by try-catch
    // from this moment, exception handling will be left on "getFileLines" caller
    return readAllLines(filePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); 
}

public List<String> getFileLinesOrNull(Path filePath) {
    try {
        // here IOException is caught, so we don't have to rethrow this exception
        return readAllLines(filePath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return null; // return null if file reading failed...
    }
}
```

Using methods:

```
public void getFileLinesTest() {
    try {
        // we are forced to write try-catch since method signature contains "throws IOException"
        List<String> lines = getFileLines(somePath); 
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Some error occurred");
    } 
}

public void getFileLinesOrNullTest() {
     List<String> lines = getFileLinesOrNull(somePath); 
     if (lines == null) {
         System.out.println("Something went wrong...");
     }
}
```

If we are handling **checked exception**, but there is no line which throws this exception, than code will not compile. Compiler knows if method has "throws ..." in signature, so compiler can easily identify such an error (therefore we are calling such an exceptions as **compile-time exception**):

```
public List<String> getFileLines() {
    try {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    } catch (IOException e) {  // COMPILATION ERROR! 
        // handling checked exception, but Collections.emptyList(); does not throw IOException 
        // method signature of the Collections.emptyList() is following: 
        // public static List<E> emptyList(); 
        // as you can see there is no "throws IOException"
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Example above is your case**, since `JSONException` extends from `Exception`, so it is **checked exception**, while in your code, there is no line which throws such exception in try block.

However, `TestHistoryModel` constructor is throwing `NullPointerException` which is **unchecked** since it extends from `RuntimeException`. These exceptions have no "throws" in method signature so compiler will not force us to handle such an exceptions by try-catch block. Here is an example:

```
public int getLength(String s) {
    if (s == null) {
        // NullPointerException extends from RuntimeException = we are not  forced to write 
        // add "throws NullPointerException " in getLength signature
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }
    return s.length();
}
```

Handling of **runtime-exceptions** is **optional**:

```
public void getLengthTest() {
   int length = getLength(null); // will throw NullPointerException

   try {
       length = getLength(null);
   } catch(NullPointerException e) {
       System.out.println("null argument");
   }
}
```

Note, we do not have to write `if (s == null)` in `getLength` method, since `s.length()` will automatically throw `NullPointerException` if argument is `null` 
and we are trying to call method on `null`. Exactly this happens in your constructor, because of this line `if (is_group_chat)`. Field `is_group_chat` has `Boolean` type. `Boolean` is **reference-type** unlike `boolean` which is **primitive-type**. Not initialized "reference-type" variables are by default `null`. Therefore `if (is_group_chat)` is `if (null)` which is throwing `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Perfect explanation...!